# Pass variables to script which called script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script which must call another bash script which varies per-user in order to get some configuration information, like so:

**somescript:**

```
#!/bin/bash
${HOME}/.ssconfig
echo "Hello, ${VARIABLE}!"
```

**~/.ssconfig**

```
#!/bin/bash
VARIABLE=world
```

Which, instead of giving me `Hello, world!` as expected, gives me `Hello, !`
How can I pass variables up from a script to the one that called it?

Comment: Source it. Replace the second line with `. ${HOME}/.ssconfig`, or `source ${HOME}/.ssconfig`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executing a script cannot affect the shell that called it, since the script runs in its own shell. To affect the calling shell, you need to *source* the script:

```
$ help source  
source: source filename [arguments]  
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.

    Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
    entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
    If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
    when FILENAME is executed.
```

Hence, the line where you execute the configuration file should be changed to source it:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ${HOME}/.ssconfig
echo "Hello, ${VARIABLE}!"
```

Note that `source` is a shell command, so the help for it is not in `man source`, but `help source`.