# Sharing variables between shell scripts

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a shell script (let's call it parent.sh) which calls another shell script (child.sh), passing it an argument.

The child script does some work and sets a value in a variable called `create_sql`. I want to access this `create_sql` variable from the parent script which invoked it.

I am calling the child script from within the parent script like this:

`./child.sh "$dictionary"`

and straight afterwards I have the line:

`echo "The resulting create script is: "$create_sql`

However, there is no value being output, however, in the child script I am doing the same thing and the variable is definitely set.

How can I get this to work so that I can read variables created by the child script?

Answer (score 1):

If you `child.sh` print on standard output `$create_sql` value, you could get it in parent script:

```
  create_sql=`./child.sh "$dictionary"`
```

After this line, you should test `child.sh` exit value with `$?` and if it returns `0` you could use `$create_sql` variable.

This approach is useful when script is like a function, otherwise is better follow muru suggested [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493746/pass-variables-to-script-which-called-script).